# Laravel Eloquent use the orWhere query in my search system request

Tags: php, laravel, search, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I tried to code a request with search system. Here the code:

```php
$search = request()->get('search');
if(Auth::user()->hasRole('admin') || true) 
{
  list($orderBy, $orderDirection) = explode('.', request()->get('sort_by'));
  $prestations = Prestation::with(
    'service:id,name',
    'facility:id,name'
  )
  ->orWhere('service:name', 'regexp', "/$search/i")
  ->orderBy($orderBy, $orderDirection)
  ->simplePaginate(50);

  $res = [
    'results' => $prestations,
    'total' => Prestation::all()->count(),
  ];

  return $res;
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to do something like I tried with the `orWhere` -> get all service name (from the relationship "with") which are equal to my `$search`.

Thank you.

Comment: what the meaning of   `$prestations = Prestation::with(
    'service:id,name',
    'facility:id,name'
  )` i want learn this one very deelpy. please help me anyone.

Comment: `Prestation::with( 'service:id,name', 'facility:id,name' )` this one... what the meaning  of `service:id,name`

Comment: @VikasKatariya It's about relationship, my table Prestations has foreign keys Service and Facility, so i can get datas with "with" in the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query.

```
$prestations = Prestation::with(
                [
                'service' => function($service) use($search){
                    $service->select(['id','name'])->where('name', $search);
                },
                'facility' => function($facility) {
                    $facility->select(['id','name'])
                }
                ]
            );
```

Comment: hello prashant can you explain me what is mean of `Prestation::with( 'service:id,name', 'facility:id,name' )`? because i dont know.

Comment: @VikasKatariya it means load only given column from relationship. From `service` get only `id` and `name`.

Comment: i tried with example but it doesn't work for me can you please send example or tutorial refer link?

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh..... It's works ! But i have a little problem : i get only facility datas but service is "null" in the output

Comment: @VikasKatariya https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-eager-loading-with-selected-columns-exampleexample.html